# Use str_replace for a whole array [takes only first line from csv]

Tags: php, arrays, csv, row, str-replace

I have found an example for this problem, but couldnt implement it correctly (still same result or no result)

i have a code which reads a csv file with rows which look like this:

`Hans,Ueli,Firma,Rang,00419999999,062 123 45 678,+4179 408 88 20`

now i want to correct the numbers and put them all in one specific format.

i made this happen with this code:

```
<?php 
//Korrigiere telnummern in csv 

if (($handle = fopen("directory.txt", "rw")) !== FALSE) {

    $row=0; $csv_row = array();

    while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $csv_row[] = $csv_data;

        $replace = array("+41", "0041");
        $correct = str_replace($replace, "0", $csv_data);
        $correct = str_replace("+", "00", $correct);
        $corrected = str_replace(" ", "", $correct); 
    }
    fclose($handle); 
}

var_dump($corrected); 

?>
```

[can you tell my why if i `var_dump($csv_data)` i get a boolean answer?]

My problem is now, that it only takes the first row of the csv file.
how to check every line with this `str_replace` combination ?

after that i want to overwrite the old results. ( but i think i can make this on my own)

Thank you very much for your time and help.

edit:

```
var_dump($csv_row);
```

will give me :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Vorname"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "Nachname"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Firma"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Rang"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "0612345678"
    [5]=>
    string(14) "062 123 45 678"
    [6]=>
    string(12) "+41793057148"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Hans"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Ueli"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Firma"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Rang"
    [4]=>
    string(11) "00419999999"
    [5]=>
    string(14) "062 123 45 678"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "0900"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you echo/print to check each rows return with fgetcsv()?

Comment: @JensonMJohn
if i put in :

 var_dump($csv_row); i get all results but uncorrected.

If i replace the variable:

$correct = str_replace($replace, "0", $csv_data);

with

$correct = str_replace($replace, "0", $csv_row);

i get the same as if i just would : var_dump($csv_row); 

(it doesnt do anything if i use $csv_row to str_replace)

Comment: Sorry Dude. Still I didn't understand what you really wanna achieve! Are you trying to replace +41 with 0041 (& similar cases)?

Comment: @JensonMJohn
yes :

for 0041 or +41 replace with 0 (Because this is the international format for our country) 

for + replace with 00 

for spaces - remove spaces.

No problem, im thankfull you try to help me.

Comment: I just want to see some rows in CSV. Can you give the pastebin.com url for CSV structure..? (Open your CSV file in Notepad or any other text editor & copy+Paste text into pastebin.com & share that URL)

Comment: @JensonMJohn  http://pastebin.com/rR5yNv3r

Comment: Replace function need to be applied for +33 & similar fields also or just +41?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not getting any boolean value for `var_dump($csv_data)`. Also Try to dump the `$corrected` variable within while loop for processed rows.

```
 <?php 
//Korrigiere telnummern in csv 

if (($handle = fopen("directory.txt", "rw")) !== FALSE) {

    $row=0; $csv_row = array();

    while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $csv_row[] = $csv_data;

        $replace = array("+41", "0041");
        $correct = str_replace($replace, "0", $csv_data);
        $correct = str_replace("+", "00", $correct);
        $corrected = str_replace(" ", "", $correct); 
        var_dump($csv_data);
                    var_dump($corrected); 
    }
    fclose($handle); 
}



?>
```

Comment: thank you, my problem was:

i put the var_dump after the fclose($handle)

it took me 3 days with your help.

merci